# How do I create an nxn array of m-m arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to create an array made of arrays in Python with numpy

I'm trying to calcule the inverse of a matrix made by some other matrix using numpy method linalg.inv() but it calculates one inverse for each submatrix instead of a general inverse

for example, lets say I have:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])

b = np.array([[5, 6],
              [7, 8]])

i = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
```

what I've tried is:

```
c = np.array([[a, i],
              [i, b]])
```

what I want is

```
>> [[1, 2, 1, 0]
    [3, 4, 0, 1]
    [1, 0, 5, 6]
    [0, 1, 7, 8]]
```

what I get is

```
>> [[[[1 2]
      [3 4]]

     [[1 0]
      [0 1]]]


    [[[1 0]
      [0 1]]

     [[5 6]
      [7 8]]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `np.block` function, which can be used to assemble a block of matrices. You can do something like this,

```
np.block([[a,i],[i,b]])
```